# After running qmake, how to make debug/release?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake

The qmake project file (.pro) contains

```
CONFIG -= debug_and_release
```

I would like to keep project file as it is but decide later (from the command line) to do debug or release build.

Currently, when I build from command line

```
qmake project.pro
make
```

It does a release build.

How can I choose debug/relase from the command line?

I tried `make debug` and it returns

```
make: *** No rule to make target `debug'.  Stop.
```

Then I tried `make release` and it returns

```
make: *** No rule to make target `release'.  Stop.
```

Comment: `CONFIG += debug_and_release`?

Comment: Project file already contains `CONFIG -= debug_and_release` and I can't change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this by followed command

```
qmake project.pro "CONFIG+=debug"
make
```